# how to hide my borderless window apps in wpf vb.net using alt+tab

Tags: wpf

hi guyz i found a code on how to use alt+tab in a borderless window apps in this link 
[How to hide form from Alt-Tab dialog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/0eefb6f4-3619-4f7a-b144-48df80e2c603/)

but the problem is it was coded in C# so when i convert it to vb.net using c# to vb.net online conversion....

from c# code like these:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
  get {
    // Turn on WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style bit
    CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
    cp.ExStyle |= 0x80;
    return cp;
  }
}
```

then i converted to vb.net using the online conversion. and here it goes:

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
Get
    ' Turn on WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style bit
    Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
    cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H80
    Return cp
End Get
```

End Property

So in my code. here it goes:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Namespace OSOASA
Partial Public Class WindowLoginForm
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        Get
            ' Turn on WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style bit
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H80
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
End Namespace
```

it gives me 2 error

First:
 **"Property 'CreateParams' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because  it does not  oeverride 
a property in a base class."**

Second:
 **"'CreateParams' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Window"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some methods to remove a window from `Alt + Tab`. 
Simply call the method `Helper.RemoveFromAltTab(Me)`.
I've tested this code and it successfully works 
when the `ShowInTaskbar="False"` in `Window`.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Interop

Public Class Helper
    Friend Const GwlExstyle As Integer = -20
    Friend Const WsExToolwindow As Integer = &H80

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowLong", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function GetWindowLong32(hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowLong", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function SetWindowLong(hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As Integer, value As UInteger) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Friend Shared Sub RemoveFromAltTab(hwnd As IntPtr)
        Dim ws As UInteger = GetWindowLong32(hwnd, GwlExstyle)
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GwlExstyle, ws Or WsExToolwindow)
    End Sub

    Friend Shared Sub RemoveFromAltTab(w As Window)
        RemoveFromAltTab((New WindowInteropHelper(w)).Handle)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. you gave me hope about the alt tab. i copied your code but when i copy, it gives an error that "winapi is not declared. it maybe inaccessible..." now i remove that winapi and it gives me an error value of integer cannot be converted to uinteger...."

Comment: @user1405327 I've corrected and tested code, pls see my answer again.

Comment: thank you again for helping me out. i copy your code and no error is showing... i already change my showinstaskbar=false and i put my helper.removealttab(me) under myform_loaded but there's nothing happen... by the way where should im going to put the removealttab(me)?

Comment: @user1405327 On any call after OnInitialized, maybe on OnLoaded

Comment: hmmmm.... what's wrong with my code... why it doesnt work while it's working in your application... :( waaaaa...

Comment: @user1405327 Can't say why id doesn't work in your app, but i tested it on loaded event of window.

Comment: the code is like this... namespace OSO --then partial public class MyWIndow ---- then insde of this is your code.... do you think this is the problem?

Comment: oh what i did i do? when i tried alt tab without the code it's working... i just remove the topmost=true... hmmmm tha's weird

Comment: @user1405327 Great to hear that it worked. And also about finding a spacial case.