# Hidding a WPF application from Task Manager - Error

Tags: c#, wpf, taskmanager

Hi I am trying to hide a WPF application from Task Manager.

I use the code below. It works great in Windows Forms, but when I implement it into WPF it gave me this error:
"**CustomWindowStyle.MainWindow.CreateParams': no suitable method found to override**"

Code:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams // <---- here is the error
{
    get
    {
        var cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x80;  // Turn on WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
        return cp;
    }
}
```

**What I must to change in code to work?**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10735902/314334

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/551847/314334) is a quite detailed description how you can set  `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` in WPF

PS: This hides your window from **Alt-Tab**, just like your original code did. I'm not sure whether it is possible (or even desirable) to hide it completely from **Task Manager**.